# greasemonkey change javascript test

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'd like to change a test made by a javascript on a website

```js
<img src="https://img_small.jpg" class="pictures_load" of="true" onclick="var src='https://img_big.jpg';
    if(this.readAttribute('of')) src='/noimagehown.gif';
```

the idea is to remove each javascript test line :

```
if(this.readAttribute('of')) src='/noimagehown.gif';
```

so I could see the big image version onclick, I tried it by removing the ligne when inspecting the page code and it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have provided so far, the intension is to prevent the function of the following `onclick`.

```js
if(this.readAttribute('of')) src='/noimagehown.gif';
```

Since above is dependent on `this.readAttribute('of')`, then the goal can be achieved easily be removing `of="true"`

Here is an example:
*Look for all images with `of="true"` and remove `of` attribute*

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img[of="true"]').forEach(item => item.removeAttribute('of'));
```